# executing multiple terminal commands in nodejs code

Tags: node.js, shell

am trying to execute multiple terminal commands through node script

i have a shell script like smaple.sh and it working fine

```
cd ~/Desktop
find -type f -printf '%T+\t%p\n' | sort -n
```

Am trying to execute the above terminal commands in node script

```
        var command = ' cd ~/Desktop'
        command +=' find -type f -printf %T+\\t%p\\n | sort -n' 

 exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {

});
```

while executing the above code am getting nothing.
first i need to change the directory then execute the second command

```
find -type f -printf %T+\\t%p\\n | sort -n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current code, node.js is trying to execute the following:

`cd ~/Desktop find -type f -printf %T+\\t%p\\n | sort -n`

if you try run that outside of node, you'll get the same results.

You need to deliminate the commands using either `&&` or `;`, like so:

```
var command = ' cd ~/Desktop &&'
command +=' find -type f -printf %T+\\t%p\\n | sort -n' 

exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {

});
```

A perhaps more elegant approach:

```
var commands = [];
commands.push('cd ~/Desktop');
commands.push('find -type f -printf %T+\\t%p\\n | sort -n');

var command = commands.join(' && ');

exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {

});
```

Comment: am getting `exec error: Error: Command failed: execvp(): No such file or directory
`But i alreday have that directry

Comment: while executing ur code on terminal it is working fine.but using exec am getting the above error